# Line integral of divergence

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

Consider the integral
$$
\int_\gamma (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) d\tau
$$
along some curve $\gamma$ with tangent vector $\mathbf{k}=\frac{d}{d\tau}$ through a smooth, orientable manifold endowed with some metric tensor field and the Levi-Civita connection. Suppose $\gamma$ starts at a point $a$ and ends at a point $b$. Are we allowed to consider a volume V containing $\gamma$ and take the limit $V \to \gamma$ to get
$$
\lim_{V \to \gamma}\int_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) dV = \lim_{V \to \gamma}\oint_{S} \mathbf{u} \cdot d\mathbf{S},
$$
by Stoke's Theorem, where $S$ is the enclosing surface? Evaluating the limit would seem to lead to
$$
\int_\gamma (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) d\tau = \mathbf{u} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{k}}|_{b} - \mathbf{u} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{k}}|_{a},
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ is the normalized tangent vector.

It would seem to me that if we let $\mathbf{u} = \hat{\mathbf{k}}$, by extending $\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ smoothly, then the result is always 0, regardless of extension, which seems to be wrong in my eyes. Additionally, if $\gamma$ is a closed curve the result would always be zero for any vector field $\mathbf{u}$, if the above result holds. However, I am not certain what prohibits us taking the limit as above.

If indeed this limit is not allowed, is there some special case when it is allowed?

Comment: If you think of a thin tube of radius $r$ along $\gamma$ (like [here](http://www.cadcamengineering.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/tube_ov.png)) then I think that your idea works, at least as long as $\gamma$ is smooth enough.

Comment: @md2perpe This is precisely my idea, but I think the "corollaries" I list above seem intuitively wrong, which causes me to doubt the veracity of the result. Additionally, it seems such a simple result I would think it would be readily available on Google, but I have failed to find anything similar.

Comment: The problem, I think, is that when $\gamma$ curves, the flow out of $V$ on the inner side and on the outer side of the curve don't necessarily cancel. Therefore the result does not just depend on the end points.

Comment: First of all, both these integrals collapse to $0$, so you'd have to start by doing some scaling. (Think of how div and curl are given in terms of limiting fluxes and circulations.)

Comment: ^ this is the key point. Once you suitably scale/normalize the integrals, you should find that the surface integral along the side of the tube will not vanish in the limit, but rather give you something involving derivatives of $\bf u$ in the transverse direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a simple counter-example in Cartesian coordinates.  Let the curve be $\tau \rightarrow x \in (0,1), y=y_0$ such that $\hat{\mathbf{k}}=\mathbf{e}_x$.  Take the vector-field to be $\textbf{u} = (U,V)$.  then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\tau d\tau \, \nabla\cdot\mathbf{u} &=& \int_0^1 dx \, \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} + \int_0^1 dx \, \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} \\
&=& U(1,y_0)-U(0,y_0) + \int_0^1 dx \, \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Thus the line integral depends not only on $\hat{\mathbf{k}}\cdot \mathbf{u} = U$, but also on $\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot \mathbf{u} = V$.